# Using a variable to call an array from an xml file

Tags: php, xml, query-string

I had some trouble wording the question, but I think I can explain it better once I show the code:
This is my xml file (test.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<entry id="1">
  <post>05/12/2014 12:00:00</post>
  <page>1</page>
  <part>1</part>
  <body>BODY TEXT 1</body>
</entry>
<entry id="2">
  <post>05/14/2014 12:00:00</post>
  <part>1</part>
  <page>2</page>
  <body>BODY TEXT 2</body>
</entry>
</root>
```

This is my PHP code (call.php)

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['p']))
{
$p=$_GET['p'];
echo $p . "<br>";
$xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$day=$xml->entry[$p]->post;//<-----------PROBLEM AREA
$post=strtotime("$day");
echo $post . "<br>";
echo time() . "<br>";
if(time() >= $post) 
{
    echo $xml->entry[$_GET['p']]->page . "<br>";
    echo $xml->entry[$_GET['p']]->part . "<br>";
}
}else{
    echo "<p>Main Page Stuff</p>";
}
?>
```

The problem I am having is with the $day variable. If I replace [$p] with [1] or [0], it runs perfectly, but I need to have it called with a variable so I can change what part of the XML file is loaded depending on the query string, currently '?p=1'.

The echo $p results prints out 1 or 0 depending on what I put into the URL, so the $_GET is working properly, but if I put either $p or $_GET into entry[] it gives the error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\xmltest\call.php on line 20
```

(line 20 is the one marked 'PROBLEM AREA')

is there any way to fix this problem so I can call either the first  or the second depending on the query string?

Comment: What does `var_dump($xml);` give you? Is there an entry array?

Comment: `object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
public 'entry' => 
array (size=2)
0 => 
object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
public '@attributes' => 
array (size=1)
...`
Is the result from `var_dump($xml);`

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way to make the solution I was hoping for work, so I worked around it by making a new xml file for each entry instead of having each entry in one xml file.
Code used to load the xml file:

```
p="docs/".$_GET['p'].".xml";
if(file_exists($p))
{
  $xml=simplexml_load_file($p);
  $day=$xml->entry->post;
  $value = $xml->entry->body;
  echo "Part ".$xml->entry->part;
  echo "Page ".$xml->entry->page;
}
```